# Soil sample composition over time

Tags: fertilizer, soil-test

I tested my garden soil (NPK for guidance in applying fertilizers) but now I'm questioning my results.

I collected the soil as per the instructions and left it to dry in a bucket.  Once dry, I left it for several months in a garage, exposed to open air.

Would this change the amount of phosphorus or nitrogen detected by a soil test?  These two components came back as depleted.

Comment: If you followed some technical instructions, then that's how it is.  Care to share the origin and content of the instructions ?

Comment: The instructions did not specify if a sample needed to be processed within a certain window

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely, unless you had just applied a volatile form of nitrogen fertilizer ([inclusive of tilling in legumes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/003807179190066S), evidently)

Phosphorous is essentially non-volatile, so drying in a bucket sould not remove any (it's lost by [leaching, erosion, and plant uptake](https://www.aces.edu/blog/topics/crop-production/understanding-phosphorus-forms-and-their-cycling-in-the-soil/))